# simpleldap import missing module error

Tags: python, import, module, ldap

The following are output of trace when I have tried to install ldap with pip.

```
 [root@reports-hammer-local tests]# pip install simpleldap

 Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): simpleldap in     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

 Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-ldap in  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from simpleldap)

 Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-1.4.2-py2.7.egg (from python-ldap->simpleldap)

 Cleaning up...

 [root@reports-hammer-local tests]# python tests.py 

 Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "tests.py", line 7, in `

 import simpleldap`

 ImportError: No module named simpleldap
```

I can't run the test because of missing module issues. can you please hep me to fix this.

Comment: What does `which python` output from bash ?

Comment: It outputs `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: run `which -a python`

Comment: Result of `which -a python` is `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: ok start python and import some installed package then after importing use `module_name.__file__`

Comment: Here's what I got `>>> import ldap
>>> ldap.__init__
<method-wrapper '__init__' of module object at 0x7fd54fcc7b78>`

Comment: I got: `>>> ldap.__file__
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/__init__.pyc'`

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Centos 7